# cumulative effect of near significant differences?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, modeling, bias

My knowledge of statistics is pretty limited at this point, so you'll have to excuse my ignorance.

We've performed prospective randomised study looking at the differences in detection rates of cancer by two different methods. Overall the detection rates are equal for both methods, but when looking at different predictor variables (e.g. tumor size, location, blood samples) after randomisation they all, by chance, seem to favour one of the two methods. On their own none of these are significantly different, but I'm wondering if the cumulative effect of all these near-significant differences could have biased the outcome?

Is there a way I could test for this? What sort of method am I looking for?

Edit: I guess should mention that some of the predictors are continuous while others are categorical.

Comment: You're looking at the predictors one at a time (not in combination with each other)?

Comment: Yes, e.g. comparing tumor size in both randomisation blocks. I guess your question is the core of my question; how do I compare them in combination with each other?

Comment: If you're combining your predictors into a single models, what are you comparing that model to?